# Отображение кода

Tags: javascript

Не подскажете почему когда в Chromе (просмотр кода элемента) в Opera (проинспектировать элемент) вижу такую картину:
[link text](http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130421/Ah6i0RkZ.jpg)

а если просто посмотреть код то:

```
введите код здесь <script type="text/dg-tpl" id="projects-list-all-tpl"> <div class="dg-location-list"> <ul class="dg-location-cell">${ DG.Online.Utils.dummy(DG.Online.busyRowsCounter = 0) } {{each(i, proj) DG.Online.Conf.projectsSortedKeys}}${ DG.Online.Utils.dummy(proj = DG.Online.Conf.projects[proj]) } {{if DG.Online.busyRowsCounter >= DG.Online.Conf.cityPerColumn }} </ul> <ul class="dg-location-cell">${ DG.Online.Utils.dummy(DG.Online.busyRowsCounter = 0) } {{/if}}${ DG.Online.Utils.dummy(DG.Online.busyRowsCounter++) } {{if proj.gap}}${ DG.Online.Utils.dummy(DG.Online.busyRowsCounter++) } {{/if}} {{ko_code ((function() { return ko.__tr_ambtns(function($context,$element){return(function(){return{ 'css':{ 'selected' : (proj.code == project()), 'gap' : proj.gap } } })()}) })()) }}<li > {{ko_code ((function() { return ko.__tr_ambtns(function($context,$element){return(function(){return{ 'attr': {href: ('http://maps.2gis.ru/' + proj.code).replace(DG.Online.Conf.selected + '.', '') },'click': function () { vm.hidePopup();  vm.changeProject(proj.code); },'text': proj.name, '_ko_property_writers' : { 'text' : function(__ko_value) { Object(proj).name = __ko_value; } }  } })()}) })()) }}<a href="javascript: void(0);" ></a> </li> {{/each}} </ul> </div> </script>
```

Comment: Шаблонизатор, не?

Comment: я думаю да, просто мне интересен сам процесс как браузеры вытаскивают инфу, просто мне в одной проге нужно как раз спарсить этот сайт, а не получается

Answer (score 1):

Chrome любит проводить о**валид**ацию кода перед показыванием его в developer console, а opera, таская код у хрома, стащила эту превычку

Comment: не подскажете в каком направлении рыть что мне как раз спрасить то что выдают браузеры?

Comment: @while chrome source code :)

Comment: в исходном коде как раз только сам скрипт, а если происпектировать элемент как в Опере то там есть нужная инфа, т.е получается браузер вытаскивает инфу и строит модель документа.